# TensorFlow that runs in Colab but doesn't on local machine

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I just started the TensorFlow course and all its labs are in Google Colab, which works perfect. However, I would also like to keep the notes of what I do on my computer, but it shows me a 'couple pages long' error, last line saying "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable" as soon as I run a tensorFlow command such as:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([l0])
```

OR:

```
dataset, metadata = tfds.load('fashion_mnist', as_supervised=True, with_info=True)
```

I successfully pip installed TensorFlow and import it as tf at the beginning of the file. Can anybody tell me what am I not doing, please?

Comment: what version of TensorFlow are you using on your local machine? You can check this by running `print(tf.__version__)` right after you import TensorFlow in your code.

Comment: You need to provide full tracebacks, else we do not really know what the problem is.

Comment: the version is 2.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try loading the dataset using keras

```
from keras.datasets import fashion_mnist
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
```

And this for the first part

```
from keras.models import Sequential
model = Sequential()
model.add(...)
```

Check the version as Leon said, and tell us.